# Rating system using http post - Avoiding abuse

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, http-post

I have an html for using POST that is being used to rate images. These images are being selected randomly using SQL.

As soon as I put it up I noticed that some users (identified using a user id) were able to put multiple votes for an image of their choice in short periods of time. It is likely they are exploiting a flaw in the way the http POST is being handled.

As a temporary solution I added some code to check if an image had been rated by the same person in the last hour. This works but isn't ideal because an image can come up randomly in a shorter span of time.

So, how could I make sure that a single rating is going towards the image being displayed and any consecutive ratings for the same random selection are rejected?

P.S: I might open this up to anonymous users so any suggestions using sessions are also welcome.

Comment: why don't you unbind click or hide the vote section after placing vote

Comment: @gowri: That's just a precaution to stop the big horde of sheeps, but it won't stop the wolves.

Comment: @gowri: It's a partial solution like the one I've applied. Once the POST request has gone through you can hit F5 or click on the back button to trigger it again. What I need is some way to say that the currently selected random image has already been voted for by the user so the rating isn't validated twice or more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a compound `UNIQUE` constraint of `user_id` and `image_id`. Then run the query in the format `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reliable way to identify users when they cast votes (e.g. users must be registered to participate), then simply store in your database the information which user has voted for which images and don't accept any further votes (or just overwrite the results with the last vote).

If you don't identify users you will probably never get a reliable system, since a malevolent user might use multiple proxies etc. to create votes for a particular image.

You could also try to obfuscate the vote counting process by issuing a unique transaction identifier for each vote which is usable only once, but for which you keep the user and image association secret. Then at least you cannot replay or fabricate a vote (though it doesn't prevent someone from just reloading the page loads and voting over and over again).